# How to get a role with my Bot in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

How can I program my discord bot to give people who write "lol" in the chat the Admin role? My bot is an admin on my server.

Comment: Admins cannot give others admin.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: IT IS SO DANGEROUS TO GIVE ANYONE `ADMINISTRATOR` ROLE AND I AM NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANYTHING COULD HAPPEN FOR YOUR DISCORD SERVER BY ANYWAY**

But because you need it, Here is your code

Based On [Github Source code](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/understanding/roles.md)

Let's say that your role name is = lol

```js
client.on('message', message => {

// get role by ID
//let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("ID-OF-ROLE");

// get role by name
let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "lol");

if(!message.member.roles.cache.has(myRole.name)) {
  if(message.content == "lol") {
    message.member.roles.add(myRole).catch(console.error);
    console.log(`${message.author.tag} has ${myRole.name}`);
  }
}

});
```